# splitting folder names with awk in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, awk

There are some directories in the working directory with this template

```
cas-2-32
sat-4-64  
...
```

I want to loop over the directory names and  grab the second and third part of folder names. I have wrote this script. The body shows what I want to do. But the awk command seems to be wrong

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `ls`; do
  if [  -d $file ]; then 
    arg2=`awk -F "-" '{print $2}' $file`
    echo $arg2
    arg3=`awk -F "-" '{print $3}' $file`
    echo $arg3
  fi
done
```

but it says

```
 awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `cas-2-32' for reading (Invalid argument)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk expects a filename as input. Since you have said the `cas-2-32` etc are directories, awk fails for the same reason.

Feed the directory names to awk using echo:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `ls`; do
  if [  -d $file ]; then 
    arg2=$(echo $file | awk -F "-" '{print $2}')
    echo $arg2
    arg3=$(echo $file | awk -F "-" '{print $3}')
    echo $arg3
  fi
done
```

Comment: and why not just  reduce it to one awk? `echo $file | awk -F\- '{printf(%s\n%s\n, $2,$3)}', delivers the same output with 2 processes, instead of 6. ... But the OP will have to tell us what the real intent is ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter I believe for whatever reason OP wants to store the values so as to use it later and posted a minimal code. Otherwise, single call to awk is enough as you said.

Comment: @KingsIndian:  what does `var=$(somecommands)` accomplish? is it the same as `var=\`somecommands\``?

Comment: @foampile: No, they are not the same. `var=$(cmd)` executes the `cmd` and stores the output in `var` whereas `var=cmd` will merely store the `cmd` itself.

Comment: oh but when i do `export var=\`pwd\``, it does store the output in var

Comment: `var=\`cmd\`` is equivalent to `var=$(cmd)` both execute the command and the result is stored in `var`.

Comment: yes, `var=$(somecommands) and var=\`somecommands\`` are both shell command-substition. The `var=$(somecommands)` is the new/improved version. Unless you need to write bourne shell scripts as root, and be ultra-backward compatible, `var=$(somecommands)` is the prefered form. Back-quotes are flagged as deprecated in 1995 'The Kornshell Programming Language'!. People get with it! Good luck to all.

Comment: There are several things wrong with the posted "accepted" solution: 1) never do "for file in `ls`", 2) never use awk just for a simple substitution like this, 3) always quote your variables. I'll post something in a few mins showing how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Simple comand: ls | awk '{ FS="-"; print $2" "$3 }'
If you want the values in each line just add "\n" instead of a space in awk's print.

Answer (score 0):

When executed like this

```
awk -F "-" '{print $2}' $file
```

`awk` treats `$file`'s value as the file to be parsed, instead of parsing `$file`'s value itself.

The minimal fix is to use a [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) which can feed the value of a variable into stdin of a command:

```
awk -F "-" '{print $2}' <<< $file
```

---

By the way, you don't need `ls` if you merely want a list of files in current directory, use `*` instead, i.e.

```
for file in *; do
```

Comment: In fact you must not use `ls` or files with spaces in their names will get their names split and mangled.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; do
  if [ -d $file ]; then
    tmp="${file#*-}"
    arg2="${tmp%-*}"
    arg3="${tmp#*-}"
    echo "$arg2"
    echo "$arg3"
  fi
done
```

The other:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS="-"
for file in *; do
  if [ -d $file ]; then
    set -- $file
    arg2="$2"
    arg3="$3"
    echo "$arg2"
    echo "$arg3"
  fi
done
```